# Can't type 'it' or 'is' on iPhone

Tags: iphone

Looks like Apple made another bug in iOS 11.1.2 and if you type 'it' or 'is' they are being converted to 'I.T' or 'I.S'. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Not happening to me on my iPad Air and two other iPhones (6S and 7.) **Edit:** confirmed by two random iPhone owners walking past my office. You must have accidentally done some text replacement on the fly.

Comment: If question/answer will be of no use within few days, I'll delete them.

Answer (score 1):

It may not work for everyone, but have a try:

Reset 'Keyboard Dictionary'. Go to `Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Keyboard Dictionary`. Then reboot the device and see if it worked.

Another option is to go to `Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Text Replacement` and enter 'it' as *both* text and replacement. Then repeat the process for the 'is'. Again, may not work for everyone.

If neither option helped, wait for the official patch from Apple.